# C++ Cannot debug from errors, but no errors in code

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, entity

I am trying to "delete" / kill my entities if they are going outside of the "playzone" or atleast what is visible to the user. I dont get any errors, but when i tried this code sample in the function "killEdgeEntities" and started the game, Everything would be dead already, as if the "if statements" executed directly. And no, i am not spawning anything outside of the arguments. For example, the users Ship is spawned in the middle of the screen.

If you guys need any more info, just comment about it.

```
void Invaders::killEdgeEntities() {
EntityVector entities;
for (EntityVector::iterator j = mEntities.begin(); j != mEntities.end(); j++) {
    Entity *entity = *j;
    //  * Dödsgränser *
    // Vänster: 
    if (entity->getPosition().getX() < -20) {
        delete entity;
    }
    // Höger: 
    if (entity->getPosition().getX() > VGCDisplay::getWidth() + 20) {
        delete entity;
    }
    // Upp: 
    if (entity->getPosition().getY() < -80) {
        delete entity;
    }
    // Ner: 
    if (entity->getPosition().getY() >  VGCDisplay::getHeight() + 20) {
        delete entity;
    }

}
mEntities = entities;
}
```

Comment: `entities` is an empty vector. `mEntities = entities;` makes `mEntities` an empty vector, too, leaking all its previous contents. Did you mean to add something to `entities`?

Comment: _"so ill be looking at the post in 30 min"_ You'll be surprised how bad things can become in such a short time.

Comment: your post contains quite some mumbojumbo. You better show a [mcve] and describe what is wrong with the code in terms that someone can understand who does not know your game

Comment: I erased the last code row, and stuff atleast rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer - since you've not posted enough code for us to work out what's going on ... but you have posted enough to see problems.

```
if (entity->getPosition().getX() < -20) {
    delete entity;
}
// Höger: 
if (entity->getPosition().getX() > VGCDisplay::getWidth() + 20) {
```

What happens when your x < -20 and you delete entity?  You attempt to access it in the next line which is now a floating pointer (ie it's not pointing to valid memory) ... and a crash waiting to happen.

Comment: Ye i see what you're saying, maybe i then have to do a for loop for every if statement? Since then it is not interfering with the others i guess. I'll try it now

Comment: @fluxe - You could solve this particular problem with an `else if`. However, you might still have the same invalid pointer in `mEntities`.

Comment: You also don't remove the pointer from the list - which means you're lining yourself up for a crash later which you won't see... the best solution is to use a smart pointer and then remove the items from the list  (delete will happen automatically)

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem, by making an else batch at the end doing a push_back on the entity to the EntityVector "entities". And then lastly after the for loop to make sure they are inline(parallell i guess).

```
void Invaders::killEdgeEntities() {

    EntityVector entities;
    for (EntityVector::iterator i = mEntities.begin(); i != mEntities.end(); i++) {
        Entity *entity = *i;
        //  * Dödsgränser *
        // Vänster: 
        if (entity->getPosition().getX() < -20) {
            delete entity;
        }
        // Höger: 
        else if (entity->getPosition().getX() > VGCDisplay::getWidth() + 20) {
            delete entity;
        }
        // Upp: 
        else if (entity->getPosition().getY() < -80) {
            delete entity;
        }
        // Ner: 
        else if (entity->getPosition().getY() > VGCDisplay::getHeight() + 20) {
            delete entity;
        }
        else {
            entities.push_back(entity);
        }
    }
    mEntities = entities;
}
```